# Previous and Next Sibling JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Okay so I've been studying the book JavaScript and jQuery interactive front end development by "Jon Duckett"

Im on page 210 "Previous and Next Sibling" how do i change the li.a attributes in the navigation drop down sub menu, i have removed all white space so that it does not pick up any unwanted textNodes in the HTML like so.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="subLinks" id="subWeb">Web Development</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="subGraph" class="subLinks">Graphic Design</a> 
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="subLinks"id="subProto">Prototypes</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="subLinks" id="subFun">Fun Stuff</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I added the JavaScript from the book to change the value of the class attributes but I am having trouble with this, it does not work but when I change the id to the `<li>`, the previous and next siblings disappear. i am confused as the code looks correct and it works on a different web page when i give the `<li>` an id. But does not seem to be working here which is strange. Any help to get this working would be great thanks

```
/*Javascript
Previous and Next Sibling for portfolio subLinks,
=====================================================================*/

var startItem = document.getElementById('subGraph');
var prevItem = startItem.previousSibling;
var nextItem = startItem.nextSibling;

/*change the value of the siblings class Attributes
=====================================================================*/

prevItem.className = 'checkIcon';
nextItem.className = 'altSubLinks1';

/*CSS
============================*/

.checkIcon{
    background-color: teal;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #3b6a5e;
    border-top:1px solid #7ee0c9;
    border-top: 1px solid #3b6a5e;
    content: '\f00c';
    position: absolute;
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    right: 5px;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#FFF;
}

.altSubLinks1{
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Use `.nextElementSibling` and `.prevElementSibling`, they automatically skip over text nodes, then you don't have to remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your markup is all packed up and unindented (due to the textNodes i know) makes it hard to see that the element you are matching has no siblings.

Take a look at the indented markup:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="subLinks" id="subWeb">Web Development</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="subGraph" class="subLinks">Graphic Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="subLinks" id="subProto">Prototypes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="subLinks" id="subFun">Fun Stuff</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that `subGraph` is the `<a>` tag that has no siblings. Only the `<li>` have siblings.

Therefore you must either set the ids on the `<li>` tags or navigate to them with [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).

Example with `parentElement`:

```js
var startItem = document.getElementById('subGraph');
var prevItem = startItem.parentElement.previousSibling;
var nextItem = startItem.parentElement.nextSibling;

prevItem.className = 'checkIcon';
nextItem.className = 'altSubLinks1';
```

```css
.checkIcon {
  color:red;
}

.altSubLinks1 {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul><li><a href="#" class="subLinks" id="subWeb">Web Development</a></li><li><a href="#" id="subGraph" class="subLinks">Graphic Design</a></li><li><a href="#" class="subLinks"id="subProto">Prototypes</a></li><li><a href="#" class="subLinks" id="subFun">Fun Stuff</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: This is great thank you so the <a> element is a child of the list item so therefore to manipulate the siblings of the list items the developer uses parentElement when it ID is within the <a> element. This is great thank you